# import file from dag subfolder in airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am writing a python script that computes for some thing. That is why the script is separated from the dags folder. In that script, I have to import a file. But I have no success since it errors **FileNotFoundError**.

This is my directory:

```
dags/
- my_dag.py
  sub_folder/
  - __init__.py
  - my_functions.py
    meta/
    - file.csv
```

my_functions.py contains the computing scripts needed in my DAG. It has to read the *file.csv* located in the *meta* folder.

In my_functions.py, I wrote:

```
file_df = pd.read_csv('meta/file.csv')
```

But the file cannot be found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `AIRFLOW_HOME` env variable and provide the full path.

```
import os
AIRFLOW_HOME = os.getenv('AIRFLOW_HOME')
file_df = pd.read_csv(AIRFLOW_HOME + '/dags/sub_folder/meta/file.csv')
```